# pandas dataframe to_dict two columns as indexes and third as value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below:

```
User              ASIN             Rating
A23VKINWRY6J92    1476783284       5
A3HC4SRK7B2AXR    1496177029       5
AE12HJWB5ODOD     B00K2GAUC0       4
AL4RYO265J1G      061579615X       3
```

I want to generate a dictionary which has 2 columns 'User' and 'ASIN' as keys and third column 'Rating' as the value. Something like below:

```
my_dict[A23VKINWRY6J92][1476783284] = 5
my_dict[A3HC4SRK7B2AXR][1496177029] = 5
my_dict[AE12HJWB5ODOD][B00K2GAUC0] = 4
my_dict[AL4RYO265J1G][061579615X] = 3
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What would you want if two columns were the same?

Comment: Can one `User` have multiple `ASIN`s?

Comment: You can use set_index, something like df.set_index(['User', 'ASIN']).Rating.to_dict(). Here the keys will be in tuples and you can access them using my_dict[('A23VKINWRY6J92', '1476783284')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can using `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(dict)
for _,x in df.iterrows():
    d[x['User']][x['ASIN']] = x['Rating'] 
d=dict(d)
d['A23VKINWRY6J92']['1476783284']
Out[108]: 5
```

Comment: This worked, thanks! How do I initialise the dictionary to 0 so that I don't get KeyError for invalid keys?

Answer (score 5):

Using nested dict comprehension:

```
{u: {a: list(df.Rating[(df.User == u) & (df.ASIN == a)].unique()) for a in df.ASIN[df.User == u].unique()} for u in df.User.unique()}
```

Note that this maps to lists, as there is no reason the resulting value should be unique.

Comment: Nice answer ... :)

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't too clear but does this do what you want?

```
>>> D = df.groupby(['User','ASIN'])['Rating'].apply(list).to_dict()
>>> {key[0]:{key[1]:val} for key, val in D.items()}
{('A23VKINWRY6J92', '1476783284'): [5], ('A3HC4SRK7B2AXR', '1496177029'): [5], ('AE12HJWB5ODOD', 'B00K2GAUC0'): [4], ('AL4RYO265J1G', '061579615X'): [3]}
```

So if this is assigned to `my_dict` then you have

```
>>> my_dict['A23VKINWRY6J92']['1476783284']
[5]
```

etc

Comment: I like this answer. Personally I'd replace `max` with `apply(list)`, though.

Comment: @AmiTavory yeah I did, but it won't work if there are multiple `ASIN`s per `User` whereas yours will...

Comment: :-) That's my inferior Pandas skills paying off, then.

Answer (score 0):

This should work as long as you have unique User ID's.

```
my_dict ={d['ASIN'] : {d['User'] : d['Rating']} for d in df.to_dict(orient='records')}
```

Alternatively you can filter the DataFrame to obtain the rating

```
rating = df.loc[(df['User']=='A23VKINWRY6J92') & (df['ASIN']=='1476783284'), 'Rating'][0]
```